# How do you add listbox data into a textBox on another webPage. Using Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, inheritance, listbox

I have two web pages. The first web page contains listBox1 and button1. The second webpage contains textBox1. I want to select an item in the list box and then click the button and have that value appear in textBox1 on the second wepage.

I've tried in the button action listener

```
textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue;
```

This throws an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I don't understand why this doesn't work because if textBox1 is on the same web page the code above will work but doesn't work if textBox1 is on a separate web page. I have added in `WebPage1 : WebPage2` to account for inheritance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to transfer data between pages by session state if data is sensitive  or by query string check this example
on button click

```
Response.Redirect("/MySecondPage.Aspx?data="+ listBox1.SelectedValue);
```

and in the second page in page load

```
if(Request.QueryString["data"]!=null)
  textBox1.Text=Request.QueryString["data"].ToString();
```